# Save text data to nested array

Tags: javascript, node.js, readfile

I have a text file with ID's like this:

```
111111111
222222222
333333333
```

And I need to parse the txt file into an nested array, because then I need to make an INSERT to a MySQL database. So the array format has to be in this way:

```
data_sql = [
   ['111111111'],
   ['222222222'],
   ['333333333']
]
```

Now I have the next code:

```
var data_sql = fs.readFileSync(`./uploads/${filename}`, 'utf8').split(/\r?\n/);
```

But it's saving the array like this:

```
data_sql = [
  '111111111', 
  '222222222',
  '333333333'
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert every entry to an array with a single item, like this

`const formatedEntries = data_sql.map(entry => ([entry]))`